# Count how many names in each column for random output

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets

first is "Inscrp" where I put the names depending on categories in different columns Second is "Tirage" where I see random names appears from each category

`HowMany = 5` in the code represent the number of names to be picked randomly The problem when I write less than 5 names the result would be empty.

**I want the names to be picked randomly regardless of their number**

This is the code for it

```
Sub PickNamesAtRandom()
 Dim shI As Worksheet, lastR As Long, shT As Worksheet, HowMany As Long
 Dim rndNumber As Integer, Names() As String, i As Long, CellsOut As Long

 HowMany = 5: CellsOut = 8
 Set shI = Worksheets("Inscrp")
 Set shT = Worksheets("Tirage")

 Dim col As Long, arrCol, filt As String, nrCol As Long
 nrCol = shT.Cells(4, 8) 'number of columns to be returned. It can be changed and also be calculated...

 For col = 1 To nrCol
 
   
    lastR = shI.Cells(shI.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column to be processed
     
    If lastR >= HowMany + 2 Then  '+ 2 because the range is build starting with the third row...
        arrCol = Application.Transpose(shI.Range(shI.Cells(3, col), shI.Cells(lastR, col)).Value2) 'place the range in a 1D array
        
        ReDim Names(1 To HowMany) 'Set the array size to how many names required
        For i = 1 To UBound(Names)
tryAgain:
            Randomize
            rndNumber = Int((UBound(arrCol) - LBound(arrCol) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrCol))
            If arrCol(rndNumber) = "" Then GoTo tryAgain
            Names(i) = arrCol(rndNumber)
            filt = arrCol(rndNumber) & "##$$@": arrCol(rndNumber) = filt
            arrCol = Filter(arrCol, filt, False)   'eliminate the already used name from the array
        Next i
        shT.Cells(CellsOut, col).Resize(UBound(Names), 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Names)
    End If
 Next col
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Like this it returns only 5 names randomly from each filled column

Illustration :

In this case the column B in "Tirage" return empty because the HowMany I assigned is 5 names

```
Sheet1"Inscrp"                 Sheet2"Tirage"
A        B                     A        B
John     Simon                 David    "Nothing"  
David    Gerard                Steve       
Jacob    Herald                john     
Steve    Paul                  Sara
Sara                           Jacob
```

This is how I want it

```
Sheet1"Inscrp"                 Sheet2"Tirage"
A        B                     A        B
John     Simon                 David    Gerard  
David    Gerard                Steve    Paul    
Jacob    Herald                john     Simon
Steve    Paul                  Sara     Herald
Sara                           Jacob
```

Comment: `lastR = shI.Cells(shI.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row` why can't you do this with `HowMany`? Edit: I mean count how many items you have instead of hardcoding it to 5.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't give any names in the results, I might have done something wrong @findwindow

Answer (score 0):

ok... so the code below sorts randomly according to the number of columns.

```
 Sub PickNamesAtRandom()
 Dim shI As Worksheet, lastR As Long, shT As Worksheet, HowMany As Long
 Dim rndNumber As Integer, Names() As String, i As Long, CellsOut As Long

CellsOut = 8

 Set shI = Worksheets("Inscrp")
 Set shT = Worksheets("Tirage")

 Dim col As Long, arrCol, filt As String, nrCol As Long
 nrCol = shT.Cells(4, 8) 'number of columns to be returned. It can be changed and also be calculated...

 For col = 1 To nrCol
 
   
    lastR = shI.Cells(shI.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column to be processed
    
   
        
        arrCol = Application.Transpose(shI.Range(shI.Cells(3, col), shI.Cells(lastR, col)).Value2) 'place the range in a 1D array
        
        '  adjusting the number of random picking 'howmany' equal to the number of names
            HowMany = UBound(arrCol)
        
        
        ReDim Names(1 To HowMany) 'Set the array size to how many names required
        For i = 1 To UBound(Names)
tryAgain:
            Randomize
            rndNumber = Int((UBound(arrCol) - LBound(arrCol) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrCol))
            If arrCol(rndNumber) = "" Then GoTo tryAgain
            Names(i) = arrCol(rndNumber)
            filt = arrCol(rndNumber) & "##$$@": arrCol(rndNumber) = filt
            arrCol = Filter(arrCol, filt, False)   'eliminate the already used name from the array
        Next i
        shT.Cells(CellsOut, col).Resize(UBound(Names), 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Names)
       

 Next col
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: No I dont want to pick only 5 names that was only my first thought 
I want now to pick all the names whether they are more or less than 5

Comment: Example : if a column has 10 names it picks all the names randomly and if the next column has only 2 names it picks them randomly